# special characters from a div with getText() using Selenium-WebDriver (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, special-characters

I need to get special characters from a `<div>` using `getText()` for an automated test using Selenium WebDriver.

The result is **?5** while I expect **€5**.

Here is the test in question:

```
var promise = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("feedback-question")).getText();
promise.then(function (text) {
    console.log('text = '+ text);   // returns ?5
});
```

Here is the `<div>` with the special character:

```
<div id="feedback-question" class="feedback-card-body">
    xxxx €5
</div>
```

How do I get it to return the correct text?

Comment: Do you specify a character encoding as a HTTP response header or a HTML meta tag?